# ImportError: No module named _sqlite3 python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I'm currently developing python server using flask and AppEngine technologies. And when I realized I need DB, I tried to use **sqlite3**, but there are some troubles:

```
INFO     2016-07-03 12:25:35,324 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2016-07-03 12:25:35,950 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2016-07-03 12:25:36,029 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:55540
INFO     2016-07-03 12:25:36,032 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://127.0.0.1:8080
INFO     2016-07-03 12:25:36,035 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2016-07-03 12:25:39,164 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/macbook/Documents/HSE/python/analyticsserver-1359/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 963, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
INFO     2016-07-03 12:25:39,177 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

And this is my **main.py**

```
# import the Flask class from the flask module

from functools import wraps

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash, g
import sqlite3

# config
#  create the application object
app = Flask(__name__)
app.database = 'sample.db'
app.secret_key = 'my precious'


# login required decorator
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first.')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return wrap


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return redirect(url_for('welcome'))


@app.route('/sql')
def sql():
    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('SELECT * FROM posts')
    posts = [dict(title=row[0], description=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    g.db.close()
    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)  # render a template


# use decorators to link the function to a url
@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome.html')  # render a template


@app.route('/main')
def mainpage():
    return render_template('main.html')  # render a template


# route for handling the login page logic
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if (request.form['username'] != 'admin') \
                or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in.')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out.')
    return redirect(url_for('welcome'))


# connect to database
def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.database)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I've been trying to find out something in Google and here, but I can't realize what goes wrong

UPD: I'm using Mac OS X and PyCharm

Comment: You can't run arbitrary databases with GAE, and you certainly can't run sqlite, since that depends on access to the filesystem. Why are you trying to do this? The documentation tells you exactly how to use the built-in datastore.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanx !

Answer (score 1):

The development environment tries very hard to simulate the deployment environment. Part of that trying means preventing the import of things (like `sqlite3`) that that aren't available in the deployment environment.

You can develop against a local `MySQL` instance. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#testing_and_deploying